# azure function service bus python - read bunch of messages

Tags: python, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Is there any chance to read a bunch of messages in my python Azure Function (using the serviceBusTrigger)?

The question is fair simple as it is. I did many tries but it seems that the Azure Function Framework after reading the messages coming from Azure Service Bus, calls the trigger function one message at time, no matter how great the prefetch value is or any parameter is set.

I would like to handle the entire fetch of messages, because when you have to handle million of messages, one at time or many at time makes a difference.

This is my configuration:

**function.json**

```
{
    "scriptFile": "main.py",
    "entryPoint": "function_handler",
    "bindings": [{
        "name": "msg",
        "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "topicName": "topic-name",
        "subscriptionName": "topic-subscription-name"
    }]
}
```

**main.py**

```
import azure.functions as func
import json

def function_handler(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):    
    print(str(msg))
```

**host.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
          "autoComplete": true, 
          "maxConcurrentCalls": 6,
          "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be need a async service bus trigger:

**`__init__.py`**

```
import logging
import asyncio

import azure.functions as func

async def hello():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus queue trigger processed message: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    await asyncio.gather(hello(), hello())
    logging.info(msg.get_body().decode('utf-8')+" is been done.")
```

**`host.json`**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {"serviceBus": {"messageHandlerOptions": {"maxConcurrentCalls": 5}}}
}
```

And I can get:

[image]

Comment: Hi @bowman-zhu and thanks for the prompt response, but this is not what I was asking for. I was trying to receive something like a List[unc.ServiceBusMessage]